# How to prevent empty lines being places between single-line if statements?

Tags: c#, resharper, rider

In Rider (basically a standalone ReSharper for those who don't know), I can't figure out why automatic code formatting is placing an empty line between my if statements.

Before formatting:

```
string output = "";

if (i % 3 == 0) { output += "Fizz"; }
if (i % 5 == 0) { output += "Buzz"; }

if (output == "") { Console.WriteLine(i); } else { Console.WriteLine(output); }
```

After formatting:

```
string output = "";

if (i % 3 == 0) { output += "Fizz"; }

if (i % 5 == 0) { output += "Buzz"; }

if (output == "") { Console.WriteLine(i); } else { Console.WriteLine(output); }
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me the setting that is doing this, but it's quite irritating when you have multiple similar one-line if-statements grouped together and Rider/ReSharper displaces them all the time.

Comment: Correction: Rider is an IDE; ReSharper is a code analysis tool.

Comment: `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> C# -> Blank Lines) Blank Lines in Code`: what values do you have for 'After statements with child blocks'? Does it work as expected if you set this value to 0?

Comment: @John You are correct, but Rider uses the same code analysis techniques and and shares a lot of similarities with ReSharper, because they're both developed by JetBrains.

Comment: That doesn't make Rider a "standalone ReSharper" though. It just means that they have included their code analysis tools (ReSharper) in their Rider IDE. If it were a standalone ReSharper, it would be able to analyse code but not let you edit or compile it, etc.

Comment: @JonathonChase Yes, that works wonderfully. Exactly what I needed, thank you. Feel free to add a question answer below so I can mark it as solved. If not, I'll do it myself just for others with a similar/same problem in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you're looking for can be located by the following navigation: `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> C# -> Blank Lines`

Under the subsection `Blank Lines in Code`, you're looking for `After statements with child blocks`. The reason this particular setting is adding lines in your case is the inclusion of braces.

```
if (i % 3 == 0) { output += "Fizz"; }
if (i % 5 == 0) { output += "Buzz"; }
```

could also be written as

```
if (i % 3 == 0) output += "Fizz";
if (i % 5 == 0) output += "Buzz";
```

The statements would no longer be considered to have child blocks, and therefore be unaffected. If keeping the braces is part of your desired style, you can set the value for `After statements with child blocks` to `0` and you'll get the formatting behavior you want when using single-line blocks.

Comment: Ah, I knew something was wrong. I changed the braces settings because I liked the look of it more, but I had no idea it would affect this particular setting. Thanks.